Is there any hermeneutic reference that clearly shows differences between God the Father and God the Holy Ghost?
On the differences between The Father and The Son, the Bible is clear with various books describing the Father being seated on The Great White Throne and The Son at His right hand, but then there is a helper who is here on earth, completing the works of salvation and edifying the church.
It is written that when the Holy Spirit will be lifted up, then the man of lawlessness or the Antichrist will be revealed because the Holy Spirit is the force of God preventing him from taking over the whole world. The Holy Spirit has inspired many Christians to reveal hidden truths through the gifts of prophecy and speaking in tongues.
At least we know Jesus Christ is flesh, The Father is Spirit, what about the Holy Ghost, apart from the Father being in heaven and The Holy Ghost being here on earth, what are some of the differences between the two members of the great us?

Gen 1:26 - Then God said, “Let Us make man in Our image, after Our
likeness, to rule over the fish of the sea and the birds of the air,
over the livestock, and over all the earth itselfd and every creature
that crawls upon it.”

This is because I learnt from the book of Genesis that God is comprised of three beings and that explains why God uses the term us when addressing himself, even though he speaks as a single being.
Is The Holy Spirit God's projection here on earth or he is separate, is there ay verse that shows the differences between them?

You say you "learnt from the book of Genesis that God is comprised of three beings". Wherever you got that idea from, it was not in the Bible as your contradiction goes on to show:  "...even though he is just one being." The Trinity doctrine states three persons subsisting in the one Being of God. One Being. Your Q is about the person of the Holy Spirit, so, not a good trinitarian question (but +1 to LGs answer that correctly deals with the 3 persons as they relate in the Godhead.)

Just adding the word 'hermeneuitic' does not (in my own view) make this Trinitarian/non-Trinitarian, and no-text-quoted question suitable for SE-BH. Otherwise it is a 'text-search' question (which also is off-topic). I have up-voted @Dottard 's answer as it answers the question. But the question should not be here.

@Anne, why does one member speak but uses the phrase us instead of me? It means the three beings are entitled to the God title

"I learnt from the book of Genesis that God is comprised of three beings" — where exactly in Genesis did you learn that God is 3 and not 2 or 4?

@RayButterworth, the number three is very significant in scripture and its true meaning is beyond our understanding, three stands for the very nature of God

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, so you didn't really learn "that God is comprised of three beings" from Genesis; it's that you see Genesis as being consistent with your belief. This eisegesis is made more obvious by your statement that the word "us" means three, when in fact all it means is more than one.

@RayButterworth, why do you refuse to believe that the Holy Ghost is a unique individual different from the Father and the Son? How do you pray? Do you just invoke the name of the Father and of The Son only?

Three Persons
The NT repeatedly talks about the three persons of the Godhead, eg, Matt 3:16, 17, 28:19, Mark 1:10,11, Luke 3:21, 22, John 1:32, 14:26, 15:26-16:14, Acts 10:38, Rom 1:2-4, 1 Cor 6:11, 12:2, 3, 2 Cor 13:14, Gal 3:11-14, Eph 2:13-18, Heb 9:14, 10:29, 1 Peter 1:2, 3, 4:14.  Note that these passages refer to the Holy Spirit as a separate person distinct from the Father and Son.  The most unambiguous case of this is when the sin of blasphemy is discussed (see below).
Personhood of the Holy Spirit
The personhood of the Holy Spirit as a distinct individual with sentience and volition, distinct from the Father and Son is established by the following ideas:

The passages in John 15:26 – 16:14 repeatedly talk about the Holy Spirit as a separate person from either the Father or Jesus, who directs the church and its members.  For example, in Acts 10:19, 20 the Holy Spirit is the One directing Peter personally.
•   1 Cor 2:10, 11, Luke 12:12 (see also Isa 40:13, 14) also identifies the Holy Spirit as a separate person because of His teaching and instructing function.  See also Rom 15:19 and Ps 104:30.
It is possible to have “fellowship” with the Holy Spirit, a relationship only possible with a sentient person with volition. See Phil 2:1, 2 Cor 13:14. (Compare fellowship with the Son in 1 Cor 1:9, and the Father in 1 John 1:3, making up the whole divine Trio.)
In Matt 12:31, 32, Mark 3:28, 29, and Luke 12:8-10 the unforgivable sin is defined as blasphemy against the Holy Spirit.  This is an expansion of Isa 63:10-14 where people grieved the Holy Spirit.  Such a sin would not be even possible if the Holy Spirit were not both a person and divine.  Note further, that these passages make a clear distinction between sinning against the Son or Father as opposed to the Holy Spirit, again, showing that the Holy Spirit is a distinct person.
In 1 Cor 12:11 it is the Holy Spirit who decides about spiritual gifts and their distribution.  This passage attributes volition and sentience to the person of the Holy Spirit.
In Acts 7:51, 1 Thess 5:19, Eph 4:30 we have various people resisting or spurning the Holy Spirit and in Acts 15:28 the Holy Spirit’s opinion is consulted.

Possibly the best verses to demonstrate the individuality and personhood of the Holy Spirit is found in Rom 8:26, 27, which says –

In the same way, the Spirit helps us in our weakness.  For we do not
know how we ought to pray, but the Spirit Himself intercedes for us
with groans too deep for words.  And He who searches our hearts knows
the mind of the Spirit, because the Spirit intercedes for the saints
according to the will of God.

Thus, the Holy Spirit is a distinct person from the Father the Son.
APPENDIX - Divinity of the Holy Spirit

Acts 5:3, 4 equates lying to God and lying to the Holy Spirit
Acts 10:38 equates the Holy Spirit with the presence of God
Comparing Rom 1:2-6 and 16:26 we find that The Holy Spirit has the authority of God
Comparing 1 Cor 3:16, “The temple of God” with 1 Cor 6:19, “temple of the Holy Spirit” shows that the Holy Spirit is God.
1 Cor 12:4-6 equates the Holy Spirit with the one Lord and God
Job 33:4, Eze 37:14, Rom 1:4, 8:2, 10, 11, 1 Peter 3:18, attributes the source of life to the Holy Spirit
Titus 3:4-6, 1 Peter 1:2 attributes the Holy Spirit as the source of life
Psalm 104:30 and Gen 1:2 both declare the Holy Spirit as the creator
Heb 9:14 also declares the Holy Spirit an essential part of Salvation.
2 Cor 3:17 calls the Holy Spirit “Lord”.
Comparing Isa 63:10 with Num 14:11 shows that grieving the Holy Spirit is equivalent to grieving God.

The Bible assumes that the Holy Spirit is divine in many instances.

Compare Isa 63:10 with Num 14:11 & Deut 32:12 – The Holy Spirit spurned/grieved is equivalent to God being grieved.  In the NT we have Acts 7:51 where Stephen accuses the Jews of resisting the Holy Spirit!  Paul tells us not to quench the Holy Spirit (1 Thess 5:19) and not to grieve the Holy Spirit (Eph 4:30).  See also Acts 15:28 where the divine guidance of the Holy Spirit is highly valued.
2 Sam 23:2, 3 makes clear that the Holy Spirit speaking is the voice of God
1 Cor 3:16, 17, 6:19, 20 – the indwelling Holy Spirit is a divine presence
1 Cor 12:11, 28 – the Holy Spirit distributing gifts is equivalent to the will of God
The Holy Spirit is essential to the plan of salvation through washing/rebirth (Tit 3:4-6, 1 Peter 1:2), giving spiritual life (Rom 8:2, 9, 11)
The Holy Spirit is the agent of Scriptural inspiration, Acts 28:25-27, 2 Peter 1:21, 2 Tim 3:16, 17, Heb 3:7

We should also note that the Bible affirms all the usual attributes of divinity to the Holy Spirit of being omniscient (1 Cor 2:10, 11), omnipresent (Ps 139:7), eternal (Heb 9:14, cf Ps 90:1, 2, 1 Tim 6:16), omnipotent (Luke 1:35, Rom 15:19, Zech 4:6), creator, (Ps 104:30, Gen 1:2), etc, except, veneration.  There is neither Bible command nor example of veneration of the Holy Spirit.  The reason is not difficult to find – the function of the Holy Spirit is to bring glory to Jesus and teach us about Jesus (John 16:13, 14).  Thus, while the Holy Spirit is God, our attention is constantly turned to Jesus.

Please don't answer off-topic questions.

@curiousdannii - this is another case where the relevant text is rather obvious.  To remove the ambiguity, I have edited the question to include the text.

The question is still not about Gen 1 though.

This is a great Trinitarian question. What we know from the Scripture, the Holy Ghost proceeds from the Father (John 15:26) and is equal to the Father because knows the depths (that is to say, the entirety) of the Father (1 Cor 2:10), and is equal to God-Son, Christ, for Christ also knows the entirety of the Father (Matthew 11:27; John 10:15), and, as a knower and examiner, and also willer and approver (Acts 15:28) the Holy Ghost is not an impersonal power, but a person, distinct from the persons of the Father and the Son. Moreover, without Him it is impossible for our human, created, natural intellects to know that Christ is Lord (1 Cor 12:3) and thus, that as far as Christ is Lord, we should worship Him alongside with the Father; the H. Ghost is definitely called God in the Scriptures (1 Cor 6:19-20; Acts 5:4).
From the Psalms we learn that the Father creates the universe by His Word/Logos and by His Spirit (Psalm 33:6), and since this Word is personified by John (John 1:1), it is a theological necessity that we also personify His Spirit. Thus, we can freely conclude that neither the Father does anything without His Son/Logos and His Spirit, and nor the Son does anything without the Father and the Holy Spirit; that’s why when evil and jealous pharisees accused Christ of expelling demons through the demons’ head Beelzebub, He condemned them for calumniating Holy Spirit (Matthew 12:31), whom He metaphorically also called “the finger of God” (Luke 11:20).
It is not that Father is above with the Son, while H.Ghost works on earth, for Son also is working here on earth never abandoning His followers (Colossians 1:29; Matthew 28:20), and dwells with them together with the Father (John 14:23). Thus Trinity in unity is enthroned both in Heavens and on earth, in hearts and actions of the believers.

Please don't answer off-topic questions.

@curiousdannii Are you 100% sure that a question curious about specific Biblical passages, references about a specific theological issue is off-topic?

The question is not about specific Biblical passages. It is at best a systematic theology question.

@curiousdannii Have you read the question to the end? It ends: “is there any verse that shows the differences between them?” What can be more specific?

Verse search questions are also off-topic.

@curiousdannii Then it should not be; change this wrong rule asap!

The question assumes that the Trinity Doctrine is true. That makes it an issue of eisegesis, not exegesis. It's unsuitable for this site.

@RayButterworth The question assumes that Trinity doctrine is true, but this is not sufficient reason to say that it is eisegesis, because for millions and millions of Christians the Ecumenical Councils of Church on which the doctrine of Trinity was formulated on the basis of a meticulous exegesis of prominent bishops (like St Nicholas of Myra, or St Hosius of Cordoba, or St Spirison) is already an established theological position.

@LevanGigineishvili, so it would be okay in this site for a Jehovah's Witness to ask questions about scripture referring to archangel Michael while assuming that he was the pre-incarnate Jesus? Or a LDS to ask about the Garden of Eden while assuming it was located in North America? Or …? ¶ If one presupposes various doctrines, the questions are no longer asking for hermeneutical answers.

@RayButterworth I get your point. I answered this question because, as my answering post also amply demonstrates, Trinity is anything but eisegesis;

And when Jesus was baptized, immediately he went up from the water, and behold, the heavens were opened to him, and he saw the Spirit of God descending like a dove and coming to rest on him; 17 and behold, a voice from heaven said, “This is my beloved Son, with whom I am well pleased.”
(Matt. 3:16–17, ESV)
The Father spoke from heaven, the Holy Spirit descended like a dove, and the Son stood in the water.

Please don't answer off-topic questions.
